# How to set 2 conflicting systemd units with precedence for one over the other?

Tags: systemd

I have 2 systemd units to configure. They both require config files set at specific locations (each with their own config location), so they are both configured with `ConditionPathExists` for their respective configuration files.

They conflict with one another on account of listening on the same port. So they are also configured with `Conflicts=`

However, in the case where both config files are present (which should not happen under normal circumstances, but might), I would like service A to start and not service B. What should I configure for that purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any precedence configuration within Systemd but you can achieve the aim with Systemd features.

```
# a.service
ConditionPathExists=/path/to/configfile.a
```

```
# b.service
ConditionPathExists=!/path/to/configfile.a
ConditionPathExists=/path/to/configfile.b
```

Answer (score 2):

If both units are queued and everything else is equal (i.e. both units are pulled in through equal Wants= dependencies), then **the unit that has `Conflicts=`** will be the one started, while the "conflicted by something else" unit will be skipped.